# SQL Server dbo and schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've stumbled across some odd T-SQL code in SQL Server 2005, which I'm trying to understand how it could work.

If there are two tables called tblScenario in two separate schemas, one is in Cache schema and the other is in Dimension schema.

What would we expect to find when we query SELECT * FROM dbo.tblScenario?  How does dbo map to one of these schemas in a reliable and predicable way?

For some reason this actually works however we don't know why?

We are going to fix it so it is explicitly calling SELECT * FROM Dimension.tblScenario, but I was curious.

Thanks,

Philip

Comment: I would have though that it wouldn't work, dbo is a schema, but it's also a user. Could it be that the dbo user owns the schema it selects? - Edit i've just tested this (in SQL 2008) and I got a 'invalid object name' error.

Answer (score 1):

OLTP Check...
1) is DBO.tblScenario a view?

Othewise, it sounds like you're dealing with SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS), which deals with dimensions, mimicing tables, etc.  More info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966452.aspx

Comment: I thought you were perhaps onto something there as we hadn't checked the views... alas its not a view either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the old version of the query in the Dimension schema I would expect it to return data from the Dimension schema, if you are running it in the Cache schema I would expect it to return data from the Cache schema, and if you are running it from any other schema I would expect it to return an error (similar to that recorded by Chris Diver).